# Storing arguments of function with later evaluation

Tags: python

I have a pretty specific question.

User gives me a function `f` and a "variables" as arguments of the function. Note, that the signature of `f` may be arbitrary (i.e. can use any legal combination of 5 [kinds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.kind) of parameters) and some arguments may have an default value. The variables are, in a simplified way, keys to dictionary which translates variables to real values.

I would like do the following things:

- Capture how the arguments were passed (to be able to replicate it later, when `f` is called)
- Check before hand, whether it is even possible to call `f` with such parameters (i.e. not wait for the actual call to detect mistakes)
- Translate variables to real values
- Save the **exact** arguments with which `f` is called (i.e. if `f` has parameter with default value, I need to know)
- Call function `f` in the way which user specified, as mentioned

My overall goal is to determine whether the two calls of `f` return the same result (provided that `f` is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)). Therefore, it is crucial to determine (for example) whether two arguments set differ only in default value of `f` (in one case being passed explicitly).

#### Example

There will be roughly the following class:

```
class VariableCapture:
    translation_table = ...

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def set_args(self, ..# someting ..):
        # capture arguments
        # compare with signature of self._func
        # save the actual arguments
    
    def call(self):
        self._func(..# something ..)
```

Here are an example of `f`:

```
def f(a,b):
    # some magic here, not really my business

vc = VariableCapture(f)
vc.set_args(1, 2, 3) # error -- too many args
vc.set_args(a=1, c=2) # error -- keyword arg with wrong name
vc.set_args(1, 2) # ok
vc.set_args(a=1, b=2) # ok
```

See, however that there might be difference between two last lines in case of the following `f`:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    # some magic here, not really my business
```

After `vc.set_args(1, 2)` the later call of `f` should passed both arguments via `*args`. The later via `**kwargs`.

#### My guesses

I think that it is possible to receive any kind of argument specification via `set_args(self, *args, **kwargs)`. However, I am not sure with that.

Also, I don't know, whether I can differentiate between non-equivalent ways how to pass the parameters (from perspective of the particular `f`).

And, closely related to the previous, whether call of `f` via statement `self._func(*self.saved_args, *self.saved_kwargs).

I admit, it's rather broad question, but any tips or suggestions are appreciated. Also, any references to libraries which might help are great (I suppose that the key library here is [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)). Thank you!

Comment: Do you want [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for learning me the proper technical term for that.

Comment: I feel like you are doing overkill. Assume the function is well behaved and the end user is passing correct arguments. Python in general follows the motto ask for forgiveness later. But if you really want to do all that stuff, a good helper is [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)

Comment: I can see some example now, when I know how to google it :) However, the fully automatic solutions (such as `@functools.cache`) probably won't work for me, because I need to be build a database from the mapping (function, arguments) to the result.

Comment: @Megalng The example is simplified (yet complicated) compared to the whole story, so I am willing to accept possibly complicated solutions. I am sure that inspect.signature will be on my tool list. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am actually surprised how short this answer is:

```py
class VariableCapture:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self._sign = inspect.signature(func)
        self._bound = None

    def set_args(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._bound = self._sign.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        self._bound.apply_defaults()

    def call(self):
        assert self._bound is not None
        return self._func(*self._bound.args, **self._bound.kwargs)
```

This does all you want. To do something with the actual arguments (including defaults) use `self._bound.arguments`, which is a dictionary containing all passed and default values.

(Note that there is one theoretical difference, which should be impossible to be detected from anything but 'malicious' c code: The actual call is actually passing the defaults and not letting python automatically handle them.)

Comment: Awesome! I've worked hard to implement it myself, yet it so cool to see that Python has a built in solution (as usual).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try tomorrow, how it fits to my already build concepts (as I mentioned, the real problem is a bit more complex). So far very deserved +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inspect`, as you mentioned, to check the number of arguments.

We should also take into account the possibility of default arguments.

```
import inspect
import pytest


class VariableCapture:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self._args = []
        self._kwargs = {}

    @property
    def _argspec(self):
        return inspect.getfullargspec(self._func)

    def _is_args_ok(self, args):
        maximum_args = len(self._argspec.args)
        minimum_args = maximum_args - len(self._argspec.defaults or [])
        return (
            minimum_args <= len(args) <= maximum_args
            or (minimum_args <= len(args) and self._argspec.varargs)
        )

    def _is_kwargs_ok(self, args, kwargs):
        real_kwargs = set(self._argspec.kwonlyargs)
        required_kwargs = real_kwargs - set(self._argspec.kwonlydefaults or {})
        our_kwargs = set(kwargs) - set(self._argspec.args)
        missing_kwargs = required_kwargs - our_kwargs
        excessive_kwargs = our_kwargs - real_kwargs
        extra_kwargs = bool(self._argspec.varkw)
        return (
            not missing_kwargs and (not excessive_kwargs or extra_kwargs)
        )

    def _get_excessive_kwargs(self, args, kwargs):
        original_args = self._argspec.args + list(self._argspec.defaults or ())
        provided_args = set(original_args[:len(args)])
        return set(kwargs) & provided_args

    def set_args(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._is_args_ok(args):
            raise TypeError(
                f"Setting {self._func.__name__} with wrong number of args. "
                f"Expected {len(self._argspec.args)}: {self._argspec.args}."
            )
        if not self._is_kwargs_ok(args, kwargs):
            raise TypeError(
                f"Setting {self._func.__name__} with wrong kwargs. "
                f"Got {list(self._kwargs)}, "
                f"instead of {self._argspec.kwonlyargs} "
                f"(defaults: {self._argspec.kwonlydefaults})."
            )
        if excessive_kwargs := self._get_excessive_kwargs(args, kwargs):
            raise TypeError(f"Some kwargs are duplicate: {excessive_kwargs}.")
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def call(self):
        return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

Some tests:

```
def test_regular():
    def func(a, b):
        return a + b

    v = VariableCapture(func)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, 3)

    v.set_args(1, 2)
    assert v.call() == 3  # Good to go


def test_args():
    def func(a, b, *args):
        return a + b + sum(args)

    v = VariableCapture(func)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1)

    v.set_args(1, 2)
    assert v.call() == 3
    v.set_args(1, 2, 3, 4)
    assert v.call() == 10


def test_default():
    def func(a, b, c=5, d=1):
        return a + b + c + d

    v = VariableCapture(func)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1)
    v.set_args(1, 2)
    assert v.call() == 9
    v.set_args(1, 2, 3)
    assert v.call() == 7
    v.set_args(1, 2, 3, 4)
    assert v.call() == 10
    v.set_args(1, 2, d=3)
    assert v.call() == 11
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, c=3)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, e=3)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)


def test_kwargs():
    def func(a, b, *, c, d=1, **kwargs):
        return a + b + c + d + kwargs.get('e', 0)

    v = VariableCapture(func)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, 3)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, d=3)
    v.set_args(1, 2, c=3)
    assert v.call() == 7
    v.set_args(1, 2, c=3, d=4)
    assert v.call() == 10
    v.set_args(1, 2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
    assert v.call() == 15
    v.set_args(1, 2, c=3, e=5)
    assert v.call() == 12
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, c=3)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, b=2, c=5)  # A tough one, identify duplications
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, e=3)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        v.set_args(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. I will try it tomorrow. It is likely that I will need more fine-grained control of the process than it is achievable solely using `inspect` module. Your work is much appreciated, so far +1 from me!